# How to get the name of a Wikidata item

Tags: api, wikidata

Let's say I have a Wikidata item QID `Q19675`, and want to get the name of that item in Spanish.

While getting a property like `P281 postal code` is easy, how to get the name, which for some reason is not a normal [property](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:List_of_properties/Generic)? Preferably via the REST API.

[image: Wikidata item name]

Comment: @Nicolas_Raoul, getting a property like P281 postal code is easy? But how? I tried to use SPARQL: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10334/get-items-properties-know-qid but maybe you know better way.

Comment: I already asked http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10334/get-items-properties-know-qid

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want this:

[`https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&props=labels&ids=Q19675&languages=es`](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&props=labels&ids=Q19675&languages=es)

The API command in English: Get information about some entities (`action=wbgetentities`), namely the label properties (`props=labels`) of item Q19675 (`ids=Q19675`) in Spanish (`languages=es`).

For more details, have a look at the [full documentation of `wbgetentities`](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities).

Comment: but cab I use Wikidata Query Service SPARQL for this?

Comment: @Alex Yes, but please [ask a new question](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), because this one focuses on the REST API.

Answer (score 7):

You can get it also using SPARQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
  wd:Q19675 rdfs:label ?label . 
  FILTER (langMatches( lang(?label), "ES" ) )  
}
```

See it on [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%2A%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ19675%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%20%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28langMatches%28%20lang%28%3Flabel%29%2C%20%22ES%22%20%29%20%29%20%20%0A%7D%0A).