# Extract labels from Wikidata entity

Tags: linked-data, wikidata

Is there a way to extract the labels of the statements (property and object) in Wikidata? I want to get all the information that there is here:https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q42, properties and objects with labels so both (wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P21, sex or gender) and (wikidata.org/wiki/Q6581097, male).

I've tried to do this using the wiki data toolkit, but I can't find a way to avoid doing multiple requests to the API (I'm now getting ids from the Q42 entities and then, for each of these, I send an API request to get the label.)

The problem is the same I've found in these two questions:

[How to get the name of a Wikidata item](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-wikidata-item)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266398/getting-readable-results-from-wikidata

There's a way to get all the information when I retrieve the data for the Q42 entity?

Comment: It doesn't seem like this is possible at this time

Comment: not even with sparql or some other metods?

Comment: Maybe try https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried that, you can get data using https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q42, but how can I make the labels explicit without using again the API? Maybe there is something I've missed in the documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with SPARQL:

```
SELECT ?wdLabel ?ooLabel
WHERE {
  VALUES (?s) {(wd:Q42)}
  ?s ?wdt ?o .
  ?wd wikibase:directClaim ?wdt .
  ?wd rdfs:label ?wdLabel .
  OPTIONAL {
    ?o rdfs:label ?oLabel .
    FILTER (lang(?oLabel) = "en")
  }
  FILTER (lang(?wdLabel) = "en")
  BIND (COALESCE(?oLabel, ?o) AS ?ooLabel)
 } ORDER BY xsd:integer(STRAFTER(STR(?wd), "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P"))
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FwdLabel%20%3FooLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20VALUES%20%28%3Fs%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ42%29%7D%0A%20%3Fs%20%3Fwdt%20%3Fo%20.%0A%20%3Fwd%20wikibase%3AdirectClaim%20%3Fwdt%20.%0A%20%3Fwd%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FwdLabel%20.%0A%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%3Fo%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FoLabel%20.%0A%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3FoLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%7D%0A%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3FwdLabel%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20BIND%20%28COALESCE%28%3FoLabel%2C%20%3Fo%29%20AS%20%3FooLabel%29%0A%20%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20xsd%3Ainteger%28STRAFTER%28STR%28%3Fwd%29%2C%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FP%22%29%29).

Perhaps the problem was that Wikidata supplies labels for entities in the `wd:` namespace only.

In order to provide labels for properties in the `wdt:` namespace, one have to use the special predicate `wikibase:directClaim`, which connects the `wd:` namespace entity for the property to its `wdt:` namespace representation.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this one:

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/Q42.ttl?flavor=full

Which generates RDF description of Q42 containing most of what you need I think (also available as .nt or .rdf). Be careful with it though - it can produce a lot of info, for Q42 it's over 1M but can be even more.

You can make more specific query using the [SPARQL interface](http://query.wikidata.org) but I don't understand the requirements enough to write an actual query.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

There is a python package called [wikidata](https://pypi.org/project/Wikidata/) using which you can query.

Here is a sample :
for entity 'Q5' you can check the label/description in eng(or other language) as shown below:

```
from wikidata.client import Client
client = Client()  # doctest: +SKIP
entity = client.get('Q5', load=True)
>>> entity.label.texts['en']
'human'

>>> entity.description.texts['en']
m'common name of Homo sapiens'

image_prop = client.get('P18')
image = entity[image_prop]
>>> image
<wikidata.commonsmedia.File 'File:KBS "The Producers" press conference, 11 May 2015 10.jpg'>
>>> image.image_resolution
(820, 1122)
>>> image.image_url
'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/KBS_%22The_Producers%22_press_conference%2C_11_May_2015_10.jpg'
```