# get item's properties know QID

Tags: wikidata, sparql

Know QID I can get items's label:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
  wd:Q302 rdfs:label ?label . 
  FILTER (langMatches( lang(?label), "EN" ) )
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
}
LIMIT 1
```

see this query on [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ302%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%20%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28langMatches%28%20lang%28%3Flabel%29%2C%20%22EN%22%20%29%20%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%201).

But how can I get other properties, for example description?

I tried the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
  wd:Q302 rdfs:description ?description . 
  FILTER (langMatches( lang(?label), "EN" ) )
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
}
LIMIT 1
```

or this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
  wd:Q302 rdfs:label ?label . 
  wd:Q302 rdfs:description ?description .
  FILTER (langMatches( lang(?label), "EN" ) )
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
}
LIMIT 1
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?label ?description WHERE {
  wd:Q302 rdfs:label ?label .   
  FILTER (langMatches( lang(?label), "EN" ) )
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
}
LIMIT 1
```

but got nothing.

Description is only for sample, I need other properties too.

**UPDATE**: Probably SPARQL isn't best way to do this, I open to other ways.

**UPDATE2**: What exactly I need: I have [Query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%0A%20%20%20%20%28SAMPLE%28%3FDR%29%20as%20%3FDR%29%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Farticle%29as%20%3Farticle%29%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%22Einstein%22%40en%20%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP569%20%3FDR%20.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E.%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP570%20%3FRIP%20.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fimage%20.%7D%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription), where I get info about item searching by it's label:

```
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
(SAMPLE(?DR) as ?DR) (SAMPLE(?article)as ?article)
WHERE {?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5. 
?item ?label "Einstein"@en 
OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P569 ?DR .}
?article schema:about ?item .
?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.
OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P570 ?RIP .}
OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P18 ?image .}
SERVICE wikibase:label
{ bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
```

I need to get the same info using it's QID, in this case Q937.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527706/get-properties-by-qid)  and got 2 answers.

[first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41536933/240564):

> Using the URI instead of the variable `?item` will get the information
>   based on the entity Albert Einstein:
>
> ```
> PREFIX  schema: <http://schema.org/>
> PREFIX  bd:   <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>
> PREFIX  wdt:  <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
> PREFIX  wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
>
> SELECT DISTINCT  ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription (SAMPLE(?DR) AS ?DRSample) (SAMPLE(?article) AS ?articleSample)
> WHERE
>   { ?article  schema:about       ?item ;
>               schema:inLanguage  "en" ;
>               schema:isPartOf    <https://en.wikipedia.org/>
>     FILTER ( ?item = <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q937> )
>     OPTIONAL
>       { ?item  wdt:P569  ?DR }
>     OPTIONAL
>       { ?item  wdt:P570  ?RIP }
>     OPTIONAL
>       { ?item  wdt:P18  ?image }
>     SERVICE wikibase:label
>       { bd:serviceParam
>                   wikibase:language  "en"
>       }
>   }
> GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
> ```

[second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41532485/240564):

> If you already have the QID of the entity you are looking for and
>   simply look for its properties and labels, you're better off using the
>   [Wikidata API `wbgetentities`
>   module](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetentities)
>
> In A. Einstein ([Q937](https://wikidata.org/entity/Q937)) case, that
>   would give the following API call: 
>   https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q937&format=json

I think both answers are valuable to be presented here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a SPARQL query that returns the properties that have a value for Q302 (limit 100 for speed). In your orignal queries, I think filtering on English is one reason there are no results.

```
prefix wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
prefix wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
SELECT distinct ?prop WHERE {
  ?item ?prop wd:Q302 .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }  
}
limit 100
```

- [query link](http://tinyurl.com/h7xnmyy)
- [my source](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata_talk:SPARQL_query_service/queries#Which_properties_contains_a_value) and [orig query](https://query.wikidata.org/#prefix%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0Aprefix%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0ASELECT%20distinct%20%3Fprop%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Ftree0%20%28wdt%3AP150%29*%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%3Ftree0%20%28wdt%3AP17%7Cwdt%3AP131%29*%20wd%3AQ211%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Fprop%20wd%3AQ211%20.%0A%7D)

---

You can then get details about each property

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?property ?propertyLabel ?propertyDescription ?subpropertyOf ?subpropertyOfLabel  
WHERE
{
    ?property a wikibase:Property .
    OPTIONAL {?property wdt:P1647  ?subpropertyOf .}
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }   
}
```

- [my source](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#Properties.2C_their_labels.2C_descriptions_and_if_they_exist_of_which_they_are_a_subproperty)

Comment: not exactly what I need, I updated my question